# Error: Activity class {com.testApp/com.testApp.MainActivity} does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

Updated **

I'm trying to fix a dynamic link issue in my react-native app that suddenly stopped working (maybe due to an update).

When I add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>` `<intent-filter>` the app I get a `Error: Activity class {com.testApp/com.testApp.MainActivity} does not exist.` but without it the link doesn't open the app.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.testApp">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    package="com.testApp"
    >
    <activity
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.testApp"/>
        <data android:scheme="testApp"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

*I'm trying to open this link like so:

`npx uri-scheme open https://my-firebase-test-link.com/profile --android`

It works fine on iOS but not anymore on android, what might've broken it is when we've updated to react native 0.71.4. I don't see any other changes to the manifest

We're using `@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links`

** When I comment this out, it works but no dynamic links

if I add `<data android:scheme="testApp"/>` or `<data android:host="my-firebase-test-link.com" android:scheme="https"/>`
I get the problem again

Comment: what were you trying to `link` ? Can you give some more details ? Are you integrating a third party library ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok the fix was to split as so

```
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
           <data
               android:host="my-firebase-test-link.com"
               android:scheme="https"/>
       </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, that worked for me as well